# Closed form for Compound Binomial Poisson PMF.

Tags: probability, summation, poisson-distribution

A compound Poisson process involves events arriving according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. However, with each arrival, instead of there being just one event, we generate a binomial random variable (parameters $l$ and $p$) and that dictates the number of events. I'm trying to work out the PMF of such a distribution. Let $M(t)$ be this compound point process and $N(t)$ the underlying Poisson process. We then get:

$$P(M(t) = j) = \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty P(M(t)=j|N(t)=m)P(N(t)=m)$$

Conditional on $N(t)=m$, we basically end up summing $m$ binomial random variables with the same $p$ parameter. This becomes another binomial with parameters $lm$ and $p$. So we get:

$$P(M(t)=j)=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty {lm \choose j}p^j(1-p)^{lm-j} \left(\frac{e^{-\lambda t} (\lambda t)^m}{m!}\right)$$

I've been thinking about how to proceed with this summation all day, but can't make progress.

Also, I have good reason to beleive that for large $l$,

$$ P(M(t)=j) \tilde{=}  P(N(t)=[j l p])$$

Is it obvious to anyone that this might be the case?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha failed to evaluate this sum even with extended Pro computation time. Also, your last expression doesn't make sense, as on the left-hand side you take $\lim_{l\to\infty}$ but the right-hand side has $l$.

Comment: Thanks, that might mean there is no closed form. The last expression intended for $l$ to be large. Let me fix that.